# backgroundWorker with foreach

Tags: c#, foreach, backgroundworker

The program does not follow the logic, I need it to do the request according to the order of the items of the listbox

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var listBoxItem in listBox1.Items)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < listBox1.Items.Count; j++)
            {
                string lista = listBox1.Items[j].ToString();
                string[] split = lista.Split(';');
                num.Text = split[0];
                v1.Text = split[1];
                v2.Text = split[2];    
                c.Text = split[3];
                WebClient client = new WebClient();
                client.Proxy = null;
                client.DownloadDataCompleted += new DownloadDataCompletedEventHandler(this.asyncWebRequest_DownloadDataCompleted);
                client.DownloadDataAsync(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/sv/" + num.Text));
                j++;
            }
        }
    }

    private void asyncWebRequest_DownloadDataCompleted(object sender, DownloadDataCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
         string @string = Encoding.Default.GetString(e.Result);
         if (@string.Contains("uva"))
         {
             this.listBox2.Items.Add(numero.Text);
         }
    }
```

The program should make the download request of the string with EACH item in the listbox

example:

DownloadString http://127.0.0.1/sv/ + num.text and check if it contains a particular string

I need it to do the following

```
DownloadString http://127.0.0.1/sv/ + num.text
if
DownloadedString contains uva 
then
listbox2.items.add(num.text)
else
next item from listbox1
```

Comment: What does it do instead? What is going wrong?

Comment: Not making the requisition item by item, only adds the first item to ListBox2

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: With this code you create `listBox1.Items.Count` parallel connections. If this is a big number, this can cause some traffic issues in my opinion.

Comment: Why aren't you just reusing a single `WebClient` here?

Comment: By the way: I see you are using Controls num, v1, v2 and c for temporary variables? This is not best practice, since you refresh those controls for every item and overwrite the content on iteration later.

Comment: Your code will be a lot simpler if you use `async/await` instead of BackgroundWorker and asynchronous methods like [WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138334(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of the old `DownloadDataAsync`.

Comment: As it is, your code has too many failure points - you start requests in the background but never wait for them to finish. This means that the `WebClient` instances can be garbage collected before receiving a result. You forget to dispose of the `WebClient` instances and remove the event handlers, which can result in exceptions. You make multiple calls to the same IP, which will hit the 2-requests per domain limit etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's so much wrong with this code, it's no wonder it's going wrong.

1. You're using Background Workers, don't, you should be using [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) and [async/await](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)
2. You're looping over every item in the listbox twice, why?
3. You're spinning up multiple web clients with event subscriptions that are never disposed - probably gonna be leaking some memory here.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
public async void ButtonThatStartsEverything_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await DoTheDownloadStuff();
}

public async Task DoTheDownloadStuff()
{
    var client = new WebClient();

    foreach(var item in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        var expanded = item.Split(';');
        var num = expanded[0];
        var result = await client.DownloadDataAsyncTask(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1/sv/" + num));
        if (result.Contains("uva"))
        {
            listBox2.Items.Add(num);
        }
    }
}
```

Please be aware that the code was written outside of Visual Studio, it may not be 100% accurate, and may not represent best practice overall e.g. You may want to download the data in parallel, which would require a change.

This code has all the basic stuff you need though.